# Joomla JEditor display() doesn't load the editor

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I've been battling this all morning and can't seem to find anything on how this works. I need the editor (system default) to show up in my back-end component.

My default editor is TinyMCE
I'm on Joomla 2.5.x

This is how far I've gotten with searching this forum and google.

Sample of my script

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );
$editor =& JEditor::getInstance();
echo $editor->display("desc", $itemData['body'], "600", "400", "80", "15", 1, null, null, null, array('mode' => 'advanced'));
```

All I'm getting is a HTML textarea with my content from the $itemData['body']. No editor. What am I missing?

THIS IS NOW SOLVED.

I did some more research and learned to use Joomla's JForm to create nice forms and have more control in my component in the back end.

Comment: well, that's ok then. there needs to be a configuration, obviously joomla just takes per default a config and hides it from the user

Comment: I have developed many components, modules, plugins etc for Joomla but this is the first time that I need the Editor in one of my components. I thought there would be an easy to follow guide on their Documentation with an example or something. But there isn't (or I'm blind) on how to use the editor. As I said on my original question the 3 lines are all I got, couldn't find anything else. I looked at the Content component back-end, but it is just a big pile of spaghetti-code can't figure it out how it initializes the editor.

Comment: your config should be available using Joomla Administration and open Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Editor - TinyMCE

Comment: Config Settings are just fine. The editor works just fine on Joomla's back-end components, it doesn't load on my component.

Comment: Joomla 5 note: Change the 1 to true if you want the buttons. 1 doesn't equate as boolean true there

echo $editor->display("desc", $itemData['body'], "600", "400", "80", "15", true, null, null, null, array('mode' => 'advanced'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );
$editor = &JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display('editorname', $this->detail->namechamp, '100%', '300', '75', '20');
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I had this resolved a long time ago! But since there was no answer and yours works I'll accept yours. Keep in mind that I solved my issue with the use of JForm for my component. At the time I didn't know how to create user friendly back-ends for my components. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 4 / 5:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor;
$editor = Editor::getInstance();
echo $editor->display('editorname', $this->detail->namechamp, '100%', '300', '75', '20');
```

or (without adding to the namespace). In this second example, I picked a particular editor

```
$editor = Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor::getInstance('tinymce');
```